# How to get ALAsset aspectRatioThumbnail size in advance?

Tags: ios, alasset

In ios, Using `ALAsset`, how can I get `ALAsset` `aspectRatioThumbnail` size (height and width) in advance (without loading the image into some UIImageview). I know I can get the full image's size using the dimensions property, but how can I do it for `aspectRatioThumbnail`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CGImageGetHeight` and `CGImageGetWidth` methods to get `aspectRatioThumbnail` size, for example:

```
 size_t height = CGImageGetHeight([asset aspectRatioThumbnail]);
 size_t width = CGImageGetWidth([asset aspectRatioThumbnail]);
```

More info available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_23).